# Get multiple Integer values from a String?

Tags: java, arrays, string, int

[It's not about converting a `String` into an `Integer`]

I need to take some digits from a `String` that is a line by console command.

For Example :

```
String str = "234 432 22 66 8 44 7 4 3 333";
```

How can I get every single `Integer` value and put them in an array?
The order of digits is not important because the `String` could be:

```
String str = "34 434343 222";
```

or

```
String str = " 1 2 3 4 5 6 7";
```

Also, how can I get digits in these two cases (with one or more whitespace characters):

```
String str = "2 2 44 566";
```

and

```
 String str = "2121     23  44 55 6   58";
```

Comment: Take a look to [`String.split(String regex)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)).

Comment: split the string into numbers and parse each one as an integer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting String to Int in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585779/converting-string-to-int-in-java)

Answer (score 6):

If you want to capture the numbers you have separated by spaces, then you can do:

```
String str = "234 432 22 66 8 44 7 4 3 333";

String[] strArr = str.split("\\s+");
// strArr => ["234", "432", "22", "66", "8", "44", "7", "4", "3", "333"]
```

**Update**: as **[Evan LaHurd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4987943/evan-lahurd)** pointed in his comment, then you can work on the array values and if you want to transform the string into integers you can use:

```
int n = Integer.parseInt("1234");
// or
Integer x = Integer.valueOf("1234");
```

**[IDEOne Example](https://ideone.com/pFlQ8n)**

Comment: Then if you want to use the `Integer` objects, you can use `Integer.parseInt(String s)` on each `String` in the array.

Comment: so i can work with a number of spaces >1 only using "\\s+" ?

Comment: @f.stacchietti exactly, the `\s+` is a regular expression to match 1 to many spaces and use them to split your string. In java you have to escape the backslash, hence `\\s+`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this.

```
    String str = "234 432 22 66 8 44 7 4 3 333";

    String[] stringArray = str.trim().split("\\s+");//remove any leading, trailing white spaces and split the string from rest of the white spaces

    int[] intArray = new int[stringArray.length];//create a new int array to store the int values

    for (int i = 0; i < stringArray.length; i++) {
        intArray[i] = Integer.parseInt(stringArray[i]);//parse the integer value and store it in the int array
    }
```

Comment: This will fail on leading space (see 3rd example in question).

Comment: yeah it goes!! thanks for the help, i spent the last 1 hour for this, haha. 
Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

Use `split` on spaces and parse the substrings to integers:

```
String str = "   2121     23  44 55 6   58   ";

// To list
List<Integer> numberList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (String numberText : str.trim().split("\\s+"))
    numberList.add(Integer.valueOf(numberText));

// To array
String[] numberTexts = str.trim().split("\\s+");
int[] numberArray = new int[numberTexts.length];
for (int i = 0; i < numberTexts.length; i++)
    numberArray[i] = Integer.parseInt(numberTexts[i]);

// Show result
System.out.println(numberList);                   // [2121, 23, 44, 55, 6, 58]
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(numberArray)); // [2121, 23, 44, 55, 6, 58]
```

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to put the numbers of the string in an array, you can also use the "nextInt()" method from the Scanner class.

```
String str = "2 56  73     4           9   10";
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(str);

List<Integer> integers = new ArrayList<Integer>(0);
While( scanner.hasNext() )   // checks if theres another number to add
    integers.add( scanner.nextInt() );
```

you can also avoid none-numeral characters using "hasNextInt()":

```
while( scanner.hasNext(){
    if( scanner.hasNextInt() )
        integers.add( scanner.nextInt() );
}
```

> remember that if you want it to become an array you will still need to convert the list or put the numbers together in a different way.